# Opening HTML File with Eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: Helios Service Release 1 and I want to open an HTML file to make changes, but it opens my .html file in my web browser instead of the HTML text editor I've used before. How do install a text editor to edit my HTML files in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

You didnt't find it? Please be very clear about your question (Edit it, add more explanation)

Regarding the question I can guess you do not have WTP (Web Tools Platform) for Eclipse.

Find it here: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

If you ask me to be more clear about the answer, I would also ask you the same. :)

Comment: Just FYI, The more answers you accept the more people will answer your questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't open the HTML file, try adding the Web Package. I forget it's name. It's in the Eclipse repo under Help > Install additional software.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the HTML file you want to open and click on OPEN WITH and select web browser.